# My unit test does not show in Test Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, unit-testing, typescript

I am trying to set up a unit test in Typescript using tsUnit. I have created a very simple test just to make sure that I am doing things right. However, every time I click on Run All in Test Explorer it doesn't show me any results! It seems as though Visual Studios 2013 can't find any valid tests in my solution. Here is what I have in code:

```
/// <reference path="../../UnitTesting/UnitTesting/Scripts/tsUnit/tsUnit.ts" />

module CalculationsTests {
    export class SimpleMathTests extends tsUnit.TestClass {

        addTwoNumbersWith1And2Expect3() {
            var result = 1 + 2;

            this.areIdentical(3, result);
        }

        addTwoNumbersWith3And2Expect5() {
            var result = 3 + 6;

            this.areIdentical(4, result); // Deliberate error
        }
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    // new instance of tsUnit - pass in modules that contain test classes
    var test = new tsUnit.Test(CalculationsTests);

    // Handle the results yourself...
    var result = test.run();

    var outcome = (result.errors.length === 0) ? 'Test Passed' : 'Test Failed';

    alert(JSON.stringify(outcome));
};
```

And in my main html file I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TypeScript HTML App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/tsUnit/tsUnit.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TypeScript HTML App</h1>
    <h2>TS Unit Test</h2>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Can someone help me find out what I need to do in order to properly set up a unit test?

Comment: You forgot to mention that you are using ES6 features. That may cause the tests to be thrown away. I don't use Visual Studio for Javascript, but that **can be a possibility** of what is going on. Try to convert it to ES5, using a regular object instead of a module or a class.

Comment: Try Jasmine unit-testing framework, there are several good integration tools exist for this testing framework in VS

Comment: @Oleg Dokuka thank you I will give that a try

Answer (score 1):

tsUnit has a few output options, you have a browser-based output, or TAP output (this is better for command-line usage), or you can generate your own output based on the raw data.

To integrate with Visual Studio, you do need to wrap your tsUnit tests in a .NET test. No Visual Studio extension has been written to allow tsUnit test discovery. You can make this happen using a single test class in your project, for example in a C# project you can write an [MSTest or NUnit test that calls the TypeScript tests](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2013/02/include-javascript-and-typescript-tests-in-visual-studio/).